# Django assert post_save signal called

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to assert that a post_save signal receiver is called when an instance of my Client model is saved.

The signal receiver looks as follow:

```
# reports/signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def create_client_draft(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """Guarantees a DraftSchedule exists for each Client post save"""
    print('called')  # Log to stdout when called
    if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        DraftSchedule.objects.get_or_create(client=instance)
```

I've set up a test that looks like this

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@patch('reports.signals.create_client_draft')
def test_auto_create_draftschedule_on_client_creation(mock_signal):
    client = mixer.blend(Client)  # Creates a Client with random data
    assert mock_signal.call_count == 1
```

I would expect this test to pass since the `called` print statement appears in captured stdout when the test is ran.

However, the test runner seems to think my mock function was never called at all.

```
mock_signal = <MagicMock name='create_client_draft' id='139903470431088'>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    @patch('reports.signals.create_client_draft')
    def test_auto_create_draftschedule_on_client_creation(mock_signal):
        client = mixer.blend(Client)
>       assert mock_signal.call_count == 1
E       AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
E        +  where 0 = <MagicMock name='create_client_draft' id='139903470431088'>.call_count

reports/tests/test_signals.py:36: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
called
```

The print statement seems to suggest that the function was called during the test, whereas the test assertion suggests otherwise. Am I missing something obvious here with the mocking library?

Comment: Try to use full path from folder where `settings.py` file and any sub folders inside is e.g. `{folder_containing_settings}.reports.signals.create_client_draft`

Comment: The signals located in an app subfolder `app/signals.py` whereas the settings are located at `project/settings/test.py`

Comment: Usually its a path issue, how you have included reports app in `INSTALLED_APPS` under settings?

Comment: Rest of my test suite is running fine, and I'm not doing anything funky in my `test.py` settings file

Comment: I am talking about `settings.py` file not `test.py`

Comment: yep it's included in my `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143993/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-jack-evans).

Comment: I would suspect that `@patch` replaces the function with a mock after it has been registered as a signal. The signal dispatcher would still have a reference to the original function and call that instead of the mocked function.

Comment: That certainly seems plausible, I'll do some digging

Answer (score 5):

Patching mock objects only works for callers that look up the method at run time. Signal handlers are held in a table, so they don't look up your mocked version.

It's a bit hacky, but you could have your signal handler call a helper function. Then the helper function could be mocked.

```
# reports/signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def create_client_draft_handler(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    create_client_draft(sender, instance, created, **kwargs)

def create_client_draft(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """Guarantees a DraftSchedule exists for each Client post save

        This function can be mocked, because it's called by name.
    """
    print('called')  # Log to stdout when called
    if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        DraftSchedule.objects.get_or_create(client=instance)
```